# How to enable libass on Linux?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I tried to enable libass for ffmpeg with this `--enable-libass` in command but it didn't recognise the command.

Does anyone know how to enable libass on Linux?

Comment: what version of linux? It is possible libass is not installed on your system.

Comment: 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.i686

Comment: What distro is what we should've asked.

Comment: i386 GNU/Linux if that is what you mean.

Comment: cea: please run the command "cat /etc/issue" on your terminal and show its output here.

Comment: CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your particular version of `ffmpeg` was built with and supports that switch. You'll also likely need to make sure that the library `libass` is installed as well.

You don't specify your Linux distro but I did notice that `libass` is available in my stock Fedora 19 repository so it's trivial to install.

```
$ sudo yum install libass
```

Now back to `ffmpeg`'s support of `libass`. You can confirm how it was built by simply running it without any arguments.

> $ ~/ffmpeg |& grep libass
>         configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx

So the version that I have, does include this support, `--enable-libass`. If your version of `ffmpeg` doesn't support it you can simply download a static build:

- https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: It says nothing to do when tried simple yum install so that means it must be installed? I did download the static build.

Comment: @cea - yes, you can confirm with this command too: `rpm -aq libass`.

Comment: Thank you, it says libass-0.10.0-3.el6.i686
so I wonder why I am getting font config not found in output. That is the reason I'm trying to enable.

Comment: @cea - see this FFmpeg ticket: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1688

Comment: ok thank you, no-one was ever able to give him an answer "closed defect (invalid)" what ever that means, anyway I will have a think on it.

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu or Mint:

```
sudo apt-get install libass-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

recompile ffmpeg with:

```
./configure --enable-libass
```

Then

```
make
sudo make install
```

Then check the new ffmpeg without arguments:

```
ffmpeg
```

Mine says "libass" is in the new config.

Then, to convert videos I use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf "ass=subs.ass" out.avi
```

To obtain the subtitles in `.ass` from `.srt` I use:

```
ffmpeg -i subs.srt subs.ass
```

Good luck!

Comment: Upvoted. Could you also add details on downloading the installation files, opening a terminal, cd to folder and then issuing the ./configure. Also explains that apt is being bypassed in order to get the latest greatest. Might be obvious for you but not for noobs. Also, we want to get more people in Linux